# Disable user interaction in some part of screen

Tags: swift, uicontainerview

I create side menu via container view and when user tapped on bar button ( menu button ) I just change constraints and show or hide side menu. But when side menu open user can use elements in all screen. How I can disable or enable only part of screen when side menu open or hide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your side menu's view hierarchy is setup like this:

```
View #1
 |_ title label
 |_ button
 |_ button
```

You can now embed it inside another view, that'll be invisible:

```
View #0
 |_ View #1
     |_ title label
     |_ button
     |_ button
```

...where view #1 would be your regular side menu view that covers, say, 70% of the screen's width.
Now, set the view #0's background color to `.clear`.
Also, change your constraint logic to move the side menu to the screen's edge.

This will give you a side menu that covers the full screen, disables taps outside it and looks like it only covers part of the screen.

---

#### Extra Credit:

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to view #0. When triggered, you can dismiss the side menu.